# What is being modified in a phrase like rock hard or water resistant?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, modifiers

“The water-resistant shoes are great for rainy days.”
“The table is rock hard.”
In these sentences, I know “water resistant” modifies shoes and rock hard modifies table. Does “hard” modify “rock” and does “resistant” modify “water?” I am confused on this.

Comment: In my opinion those two terms aren't really comparable, because saying something is "hard" still makes complete sense, but saying something is "resistant" doesn't.

Comment: But in "The table is rock hard", "rock hard" doesn't modify "table". It's a predicative complement, not a modifier.

Comment: In my opinion they are not comparable because _resistant to water_ is not analogous to _as hard as a rock_.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the term _modify_ grammatically here. These are compound adjectives and have their own internal meanings. _Modification_ is a specific grammatical term that doesn't apply to every adjective, and usually doesn't apply to compounds.

Comment: 'Rock' in 'rock hard' answers (rather poetically) the question 'How hard?' and is a less semantically-bleached variant of the intensifier 'very'. In the classification system I usually use, it's a 'modifier-of-adjective'. // 'Water-resistant' (it would be better to also  use it prenominally to avoid secondary issues in your question) is much less amenable to analysis as two words, as nnnnnn points out. It arguably has single lexeme status, alongside 'waterproof'.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the first word in the compound adjective is sometimes a modifier, sometimes a complement, and sometimes changes the meaning completely. There is a brief discussion of this in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1656-1657:

> ### Noun + adjective compounds
>
> The majority of compounds with an adjective as second component have a
> noun as the first. In general, there is no contrast here between a
> compound and a syntactic construction since adjectives take only a
> highly restricted type of NP as pre-head dependent (cf. Ch. 6, §3.2):
> the syntactic dependents of adjectives are generally pre-head adverbs
> or post-head PPs and clauses. Many noun + adjective compounds involve
> a high degree of lexicalisation, as in:
>
> [25] *colour-fast, foot-loose, headstrong, threadbare, top-heavy*
>
> Although there is a more or less obvious connection between the
> meaning of the whole and that of the adjective head, none of these
> satisfy the test for hyponymy. *He is headstrong*, for example, does
> not entail *He is strong*, and something can be top-heavy even though
> it is as a whole relatively light. We will not attempt a comprehensive
> review of the patterns to be found, but will illustrate a selection of
> the more productive ones.
>
> Comparative/intensifying [26]
>
> i
>
> *bone-dry, crystal-clear, dirt-cheap, dog-tired, feather-light, ice-cold, paper-thin, razor-sharp, rock-hard, stone-deaf*
>
> ii
>
> *bottle-green, brick-red, jet-black, snow-white, steel-blue*
>
> Here the noun indicates a standard of comparison: “dry as a bone”,
> “clear as crystal”, etc. Very often, as in [i], the effect is to
> intensify: *bone-dry* means “extremely/completely dry”, and so on. A
> special case of the comparative type is that of colour adjectives, as
> in [ii]; *jet-black* and *snow-white* are intensifying, but the others
> simply specify a particular shade of the colour. Compounds of this
> type are clearly hyponymic: if you are dog-tired, then necessarily you
> are tired, and so on.
>
> Measure terms
>
> [27]
>
> *ankle-deep, shoulder-high, skin-deep, state-wide, week-long*
>
> This is a productive pattern, with the noun indicating extent. *Wide*
> here has to do with area rather than the one-dimensional measure
> denoted by *wide* on its own, and *skin-deep* “superficial” is a
> further example of lexicalisation. Compounds formed on this pattern
> are non-hyponymic: *The water was ankle-deep*, for example, does not
> entail *The water was deep*. We noted earlier that there may be a
> variety of reasons why a compound might fail the hyponymy test: in the
> present case it is due to the fact that the adjectives are gradable
> ones that can apply either to the scale generally (How deep is the
> water?) or to an area of the scale greater than some relevant norm
> (The water is deep). The compound involves the first use, whereas the
> adjectives are generally interpreted in the second way when standing
> alone.
>
> Incorporated complement/modifier
>
> [28]
>
> *accident-prone, burglar-proof, camera-shy, carsick, cholesterol-free*
>
> *class-conscious, girl-crazy, oil-rich, power-mad, praiseworthy*
>
> *snow-blind, tax-free, travel-weary, user-friendly, watertight*
>
> These are comparable to syntactic constructions where the adjective
> has a following PP as dependent, complement, or modifier - compare
> *prone to accidents, proof against burglars, crazy about girls, rich in oil*, etc. *Free* (both in the sense “not having to pay”, as in
> *tax-free*, and in the sense “not containing”, as in *cholesterol- free*) is particularly productive. Some adjectives, such as *crazy,
> free, mad, rich, weary, worthy*, occur readily both in compounds and
> in syntactic constructions, while others, such as proof and tight,
> prefer or require the compound form. Others again take syntactic
> complements but hardly form compounds: *fond of animals, keen on
> sport, eager for revenge* (compare **animal-fond*,
> **sport-keen*/**sports-keen*, **revenge-eager*). Where the noun corresponds to a syntactic complement, the compounds are generally not
> hyponymic: tax-free goods aren’t (necessarily) free, nor is a
> user-friendly computer manual a friendly one. With *prone* and *proof*
> the issue does not in fact arise since they cannot stand alone without
> complements - and indeed the same applies to free and conscious in the
> senses they have in *cholesterol-free* and *class-conscious*.
>
> *Self* compounds
>
> [29]
>
> *self-confident, self-concious, self-evident, self-important, self-righteous*
>
> There are a great many adjectives with *self* as the first component;
> many belong in the verb-centred category (*self-denying,
> self-declared*), but there are a considerable number which are
> adjective-centred, like those in [29]. A high proportion apply to
> humans (but cf. *self-evident, self-contradictory*). A few are
> hyponymic (*self-confident, self-contradictory*), while others are
> clearly not (*self-important, self-righteous*).

The above are sometimes found without hyphens.

> Indeed, a review of accident records for major airline equipment in
> the past few years seem to indicate that GE and Airbus are no more
> **accident prone** than others, such as main competitor engine-maker Pratt & Whitney. (San Francisco Chronicle; 2001-11-13)
>
> The **week long** operation ended on Thursday. ICE officers in L.A.
> reportedly just finished a similar operation. (Los Angeles Times;
> 2019-07-13)
>
> The same spectra of Ka and Fk were seen in the work of Koren (1999),
> who pointed out that this **brick red** dye (Ka), which was extracted
> from textiles, is found only in an oak-kermes coccoid scale species
> and is not present in any plant or cochineal insect. (ACAD:
> Bioscience; Dec2005, Vol. 55 Issue 12)
>
> He didn't feel called on to mention the extra vote for himself the
> widow would bring into the Beat. Nor his anxiety that Woodrow, being
> too **foot loose** and fancy free, might light out for the bottom and
> never put a vote in a ballot box. (FIC: The Mississippi Quarterly Fall
> 2001; The Best Laid Plans; John Faulkner)
>
> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Phrases like "rock-hard" and "water-resistant" are a special subclass of idioms in English (and other Germanic languages: cf. German "wasserdicht", "feuerfest"). Sometimes they are single words ("fireproof"). They are a strange kind of idiom because their meaning is not metaphorical (as with most idioms) but is not entirely determinable from merely the sum of their parts either (as with phrases that aren't idioms). "Water-resistant" is a compound adjective and, as an adjective, modifies nouns. It represents a kind of "shorthand" for "resistant to water", i.e. the shoes are resistant (adjective) and they are resistant "to water" (where "to water" would, grammatically speaking, be an adverb describing how, or in what way, something is resistant).

Because these types of phrases (like "resistant to water" or "proof(ed) against fire") are so common, in Germanic languages at least (not sure about other language families) they get "shortened" to a compound adjective in which the noun from the original adverb phrase ("to water") gets shortened and stuck on to the beginning. The general rule is to hyphenate the compounds if they consist of two or more elements and appear before a noun, and otherwise not to hyphenate.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, As in your first usage "water-resistent", they should be hyphenated, The act as a single word adjective. From [grammerly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/)

> A compound modifier is made up of two words that work together to
> function like one adjective. When you connect words with the hyphen,
> you make it clear to readers that the words work together as a unit of
> meaning.

If you left off the hyphen the meaning is still that of a single word adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and the short answer is yes, they modifier the modifiers while still acting as a single unit to modify the subject. By the way you worded your question, I can tell you understand the concept of compound modifiers, but I'll still include the information on them below in my answer - since others may have this same question while not possessing your understanding of the concept. I don't have sources written down on this anywhere, but I'm sure I could find some if you need it. I've taught English Language Arts for about 16 or 17 years, and I love studying both linguistics and grammar.

Something important to remember as that the function of words, phrases, and clauses can be different than their individual parts of speech. For example, "hard" can be an adverb when "my students work hard" because it explains how they work. It can also be an adjective when "students think my class is hard". It can also be a compound modifier when "Hard-working students are often rewarded."

In your example sentences. You have two different grammatical constructions and they both use compound modifiers (one adjectival phrase working to modify a noun or pronoun). Your compound modifiers are each made up of adverbial nouns (nouns or noun phrases that behave like adverbs and adjectives) and adjectives.

The first one, "The water-resistant shoes are great for rainy days.", uses the compound modifier (water-resistant) to modify the subject (shoes). The adverbial noun (water) modifies the adjective (resistant). Together, they modify the subject (shoes).

For the above sentence, here are the functions:

- "Shoes" = Subject
- "water-resistant" = Modifying the subject (shoes). Water resistant is behaving as a single modifier here.
- "are" = linking verb. "are" links the subject (shoes) to the complement (great).
- "great" = complement (LVCA). "great" is a complement that completes the linking verb (are).
- "for rainy days" = Prepositional Phrase. "for rainy days" is a prepositional phrase made up of the preposition (for), a modifier (rainy), and the object of the preposition (days).
- "The" = article pointing to shoes.

The current construction allows "water-resistant" to modify shoes.

The second construction, "The table is rock hard", also makes use of a compound modifier to modify the subject. The difference is the compound modifier comes after the noun it modifies and doesn't need a hyphen (like water-resistant shoes).
For the above sentence, here are the functions:

- The = Article pointing to the subject (table)
- table = Subject
- is = Linking Verb connecting the subject and compound modifier
- rock hard = compound modifier describing the table and completing (LVCA) the linking verb.

The current construction also allows for both words to behave as one modifier and describe the table.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with all that you say. For example, the verb "be" when used predicatively takes complements, not modifiers. Thus, in "The table is rock hard", the adjective phrase "rock hard" does not modify "table" but is a predicative complement of the verb "be". Note that obligatory elements are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase.

Comment: Bill, I think I'm following what you're saying, and I think we're intending to say the same thing. What I was saying is that "rock hard" is playing the role of a Linking Verb Complement Adjective. It's describing the table while completing the linking verb "is" - which is a form of the verb "be". Are we in agreement or is that disagreeing on this? I'm having a hard time following. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, my point was just that "rock hard" is a complement of "be", not a modifier of "table".

Comment: Bill, is it possible for it to be a complement of "be" - while its function is modifying or describing table? I was attempting to differentiate the function of the phrase with the part of speech. If I'm wrong, let me know, and I'll edit my answer. I thought long and hard on this original answer before responding, LOL.

Comment: It is describing, but _not_ modifying, "table". Such predicative complements are often called 'subjective' because although they are complements of the verb, they refer to the subject. Compare "We painted the house white", where "white" is 'objective' predicative complement. It describes the house, but it is complement of the verb "painted". Please also see my first comment above.

Comment: Bill, Good point. So, would it be fair to say that the phrase "rock hard" is a predicative adjective because it is describing the table, but its function in this sentence is a predicative complement - since the information the phrase provides isn't just additional information about the table, but it's information that is necessary for the sentence to make sense or meaning? I see your point about it being a compliment instead of a modifier.

Comment: Yes, the AdjP complement is necessary to syntactically complete the verb phrase. If it's dropped the sentence becomes ungrammatical. This is the rule: 'Obligatory elements are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase; optional elements may be either complements or adjuncts'.